# can I run binary code for arm-7 on other devices?

Tags: java-native-interface, arm

I have an image compiled successfully for a mobile device. I now want to run it on another device. Can I potentially use the compiled binary? I do not care about having all the functionality right now. I just want to call one of the functions in the code and get a response. 
Is it possible to add the compiled code as a shared library in a JNI project?

@Alex - Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library is built for some runtime, e.g. iOS or Linux or Windows. It cannot run on a different type of system, but usually quite easily runs on another device of the same kind.